# Prove $2\int_a^b\left[f(x)\int_x^bf(y)\,dy\right]dx=\left[\int_a^bf(x)\,dx\right]^2$

Tags: calculus

> Suppose $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Prove that $$2\int_a^b\left[f(x)\int_x^bf(y)\,dy\right]dx=\left[\int_a^bf(x)\,dx\right]^2.$$

I got to $$\left[\int_a^bf(x)\,dx\right]^2=\int_a^bf(x)\left[\int_a^xf(y)\,dy+\int_x^bf(y)\,dy\right]dx$$ and I hoped to show that as $x$ ranges from $[a,b]$, the integrals $\int_a^x$ and $\int_x^b$ might take on the same values, but that's not the case. What should my next step be?

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_a^b\left[f(x)\int_x^bf(y)dy\right]dx &= \int_a^b\left[\int_x^bf(y)dy\right]d\left(\int_a^xf(y)dy\right) = \\
&= |\text{integration by parts}| = \\
&= \underbrace{\left.\int_x^bf(y)dy\int_a^xf(y)dy\right|_a^b}_{=0}- \int_a^b\left[\int_a^xf(y)dy\right]d\left(\int_x^bf(y)dy\right) = \\
&= -\int_a^b\left[\int_a^xf(y)dy\right]\left(-f(x)\right)dx = \\
&= \int_a^b\left[f(x)\int_a^xf(y)dy\right]dx
\end{aligned}
$$

Now, we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
2\int_a^b\left[f(x)\int_x^bf(y)dy\right]dx &= \int_a^b\left[f(x)\int_x^bf(y)dy\right]dx+\int_a^b\left[f(x)\int_x^bf(y)dy\right]dx = \\
&=\int_a^b\left[f(x)\int_a^xf(y)dy\right]dx+\int_a^b\left[f(x)\int_x^bf(y)dy\right]dx = \\
&=\int_a^bf(x)\left[\int_a^xf(y)dy+\int_x^bf(y)dy\right]dx = \\
&=\int_a^bf(x)\left[\int_a^bf(y)dy\right]dx = \\
&= \left[\int_a^bf(y)dy\right]\left[\int_a^bf(x)dx\right] = \left[\int_a^bf(x)dx\right]^2
\end{aligned}
$$